# Post Json API giving error 500, what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to create a new client in my API using php cURL. Clients, products and everything that is created is by POST method. This is my code:

```
$json='{
"data": {
    "type": "customers",
    "attributes": {
        "tax_registration_number": "5555555550",
        "business_name": "Test customer",
        "contact_name": "Mr. Test",
        "website": "https://www.testurl.pt",
        "phone_number": "2299999999",
        "mobile_number": "9299999999",
        "email": "test@testcustomer.pt",
        "observations": "This is only a test",
        "internal_observations": "This is good customer",
        "not_final_customer": null,
        "cashed_vat": null,
        "tax_country_region": "PT-MA"
    },
    "relationships": {
        "main_address": {
            "data": {
                "type": "addresses",
                "id": 1
            }
        },
        "addresses": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "type": "addresses",
                    "id": 1
                },
                {
                    "type": "addresses",
                    "id": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
}';
 print($json);
```

Here I iniciate the cURL, I have the token and the authorization already:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,($url));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,($json));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump ($response);
$response=json_decode($response,true);
curl_close ($ch);
```

This is the response that I have:

```
string(329) "{"errors":[{"status":"500 Internal Server Error","code":"JA006","detail":"Erro de sistema JA006: erro interno na base de dados. Por favor contacte o suporte técnico.","meta":{"internal-error":"in JsonapiJson::Value::operator[](ArrayIndex)const: requires arrayValue"}}],"jsonapi":{"version": "1.0","meta":{"libversion":"2.4.1"}}}"
```

Can someone please help me?
Thanks!

Comment: `application/vnd.api+json` looks a bit suspect. `application/json` is the normal JSON content type (just like in your accept header). Other than that, a 500 error is really a server side error so you'd have to contact the maintainers of the API to find out why it crashed. Personally I can't see anything else obviously wrong with your code, but perhaps someone else will spot something

Comment: You're receiving `JA006 system error: internal database error. Please contact technical support.` from the API, so contact their technical support

Answer (score 1):

The API error states this: `in JsonapiJson::Value::operator[](ArrayIndex)const: requires arrayValue`.

Are you *sure* that JSON is the correct format? It seems like you are probably providing an *object* in the JSON where the server expects an *array of objects*. For example, check if `data`, or `relationships`, or `addresses` should be arrays.

My top guess would be instead of:

```json
"addresses": {
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "addresses",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "addresses",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

*Maybe* it's supposed to be

```json
"addresses":[
  {
    "type": "addresses",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "type": "addresses",
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

I certainly can't tell you for sure, since I don't know the API you are trying to use, but I highly suspect it's a case like this where it's expecting an array, but you're providing an object.